# Who becomes king?

Tags: contest-math, puzzle

5 earls argue which becomes king and which becomes treasurer.

**A** will be happy only if **D** or **E** is treasurer.

**B** will be happy only if **C** is treasurer.

**C** will be happy only if **D** is either king or treasurer.

**D** will be happy only if **A** is king or treasurer.

**E** will be happy only if **A** is not king.

It is not possible for all five to be happy,so in the end they appoint king and treasurer so that the other 3 will be happy.

Forming a table,I find that **D** will be treasurer since **A**,**C** and **E** will be happy.So that eliminates **D** as king.Then,how can I proceed further since only **C**,**D** and **E** states who they want to be king.

Edit:I forgot to type in part of the question.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Make everyone happy? Because that can't be done (B, D and E's requirements are incompatible).

Comment: Sorry.It's edited now.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the rules - are you picking so that the three remaining people are all happy, without considering the feelings of the two chosen? If so, it seems B should be king, and D should be treasurer. Once you select D as treasurer, which satisfies A and C, B can't be happy, so he must be king (note that B being king does not make A, C or E unhappy).

Comment: Oh hmm,the answer says it's B.So once I select D as treasurer,that already makes A and C happy right?Leaving only E's statement which is A not being king.Doesn't that make anyone being king happy then?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi: no, it must specifically be B, because D being treasurer makes him unhappy no matter who is king, unless you make *him* king. Once you select D as treasurer, B has to be king - and since E's only requirement is that A not be king, everyone is happy.

Comment: So we assume making B,who is unhappy,become king will make him happy?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi: well, this is where things aren't entirely clear to me. By *your* description of the rules, it sounds like you want to chose a treasurer (T) and king (K) among A, B, C, D, E such that the remaining three members are happy. So once we've chosen T and K, we just need to make sure the remaining three members are happy, which A C and E are in this case. This is the only way I can make sense of the stated rules.

Comment: Oh okay.the question was phrased like this.Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We start with

$$\begin{array} \\ \tag{1}
    a &:& t(d) \lor t(e) \\
    b &:& t(c) \\
    c &:& k(d) \lor t(d) \\
    d &:& k(a) \lor t(a) \\
    e &:&  \lnot k(a)
\end{array}$$

So we have five statements (a,b,c,d,e). All statements except the statement of the king and 
the treasurer must be true. We have some additional conditions $(2)$ that must be true:

- there is exactly one treasurer
- there exactly one king
- the king cannot be the treasurer

To simplify 
the processing of the statements $81)$ we augment each statement $x$ ($x \in  \{a,b,c,d,e\}$) by $t(x) \lor k(x)$ .

Now we can search for a solution such that $(2)$ and all filve statements in $(3)$ are true.

$$\begin{array} \\ \tag{3}
    a &:& t(d) \lor t(e) \lor k(a) \lor t(a) \\
    b &:& t(c) \lor k(b) \lor t(b) \\
    c &:& k(d) \lor t(d) \lor k(c) \lor t(c) \\
    d &:& k(a) \lor t(a) \lor k(d) \lor t(d) \\
    e &:&  \lnot k(a) \lor k(e) \lor t(e)
\end{array}$$

We reorder the terms 
$$\begin{array} \\
    a &:& k(a) \lor t(a) \lor t(d) \lor t(e)  \\ \tag{4}
    b &:& k(b) \lor t(b) \lor t(c)  \\
    c &:& k(d) \lor k(c) \lor t(c) \lor t(d) \\
    d &:& k(a) \lor k(d) \lor t(a) \lor t(d) \\
    e &:& k(b) \lor k(c) \lor k(d) \lor k(e) \lor t(e)
\end{array}$$

and see that it statement $a$ and statement $b$ are both true then $k(a) \lor k(b)$ must be true ans so 
we have

$$\lnot k(c),  \lnot k(d),  \lnot k(e) \tag{5}$$

If we apply $(5)$ on $(4)$ we get:

$$\begin{array} \\ \tag{6}
    a &:& k(a) \lor t(a) \lor t(d) \lor t(e)  \\
    b &:& k(b) \lor t(b) \lor t(c)  \\
    c &:& t(c) \lor t(d) \\
    d &:& k(a) \lor t(a) \lor t(d) \\
    e &:& k(b) \lor t(e)
\end{array}$$

and from statement $c$ in $(6)$ we conclude

$$\lnot t(a), \lnot t(b), \lnot t(e) \tag{7}$$

$(7)$ applied to $(6)$ gives

$$\begin{array} \\ \tag{8}
    a &:& k(a) \lor t(d) \\
    b &:& k(b) \lor t(c)  \\
    c &:& t(c) \lor t(d) \\
    d &:& k(a) \lor t(d) \\
    e &:& k(b)
\end{array}$$

From statement $e$ and $a$ and $(2)$ follows $t(d)$. $k(b)$ and $t(d)$ satisfy all statements of $(8)$ (and therefore $(3)$)and $(2)$.

Comment: I edited the answer. Feel free to change it if you're unhappy with this!

Comment: I was unhappy with this solution  and I am neither a king nor a treasurer so I have to be happy.